# audio stream with auto RAM usage

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm doing a very simple BOT for discord where basically it will play my shoutcast radio in a room on the discord.

Code:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    let args = message.content.substring(1).split(' ')

    if (args[0] === 'play') {
        connected = message.member.voice.channel.join().then(
            connection => {
                connected = connection.play('http://mystation.com/stream.mp3')
            }
        )
    }
})
```

Basically the user will enter an audio room and type !play and the bot will enter that room to start playing the radio

It normally plays the radio, but the audio is constantly locking up and I noticed that there is high consumption of RAM only with this code, it is exceeding 100 MB. Does anyone have any suggestions or optimization tips to reduce this excess RAM? I would like to understand why this occurs

Comment: Does this stream the audio to the channel or just direct the channel or just direct the channel to play something? Do you mean RAM as in your Node(?) process?

Comment: @tadman Yes, consumption is with my node process. I noticed this problem when I hosted my bot on a plan that provided me with 100MB of RAM and the bot was shut down due to excess RAM

Comment: And he's streaming radio on a voice channel. Basically I have a radio that is being broadcast on my website (mysite.com/stream), I took this link and played in the connection.play () function to also broadcast on discord.

Comment: Does this Node process handle the streaming of the data directly? Does it read in that MP3 file into memory? Does this memory limit get tripped if you disable that line?

Comment: @tadman Yes, nodejs handles data streaming directly. The RAM consumption of the application without using this audio stream command is 25MB of RAM, when you use it after a few seconds it exceeds 100MB and the application stops working due to RAM limitation.

Comment: Best thing I could think of was bitrate reduction, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53896239/10598767) could help you save up enough RAM.

Comment: Thanks for the answer despite the date of the question. I had particularly left that aside to see in the future, but I will test what you commented on when you mess with bots again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Discord music bots often take a lot of RAM. There's not much you can do about this, however, you could try switching to Eris, which is a similar library that is older and has less memory usage.